# Настройка htaccess запрет на запуск php файлов в каталоге и под каталогах

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

В корне сайте лежит основной htaccess файл index.php и несколько папок (img, controllers, models, view). В папке img множество папок и файлов разной вложенности. Что написать в htaccess, чтобы из папки img и во вложенных в ней папках не запускались php файлы? В идеале, что бы в лог записывались попытки запустить такие файлы.

Может не в основном htaccess нужно что то прописывать, а создать еще htaccess в img папке и там прописать настройки

Answer (score 0):

Внутрь папки img добавить .htaccess с текстом

Deny from all

или

Order allow,deny

Deny from all